# Google Maps API - Setting 3 lat/long points

Tags: google-maps, google-directions-api

In a url we wish to set 3 points for the trip, not just two like this example:

http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=49.34593,-123.1807&daddr=49.35037,-123.1749

How do we do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=49.34593,-123.1807&daddr=49.35037,-123.1749+to:49.350,-123.17

I just added +to: and a third lat/lng. Your best bet is to just get the map the way you want it, then click the link icon in the upper right and pull out the generated URL.

Comment: That worked exactly as needed, the route is laid out as needed.

Comment: Awesome, make sure to click accept if it really does do the trick :)